# Packet Listener in Android Service

Tags: android, service, widget, xmpp

I am trying to create a service for a chat widget using XMPP, which picks up chat messages when they are sent to the user.

I have created a service, and in the onStart I use a AsyncTask to connect to the chat server, and then sets up a packetlistener.

Here's the code for the packer listener:

```
public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
    if (connection != null) {
        // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
        PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                    String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                            .getFrom());
                    Log.v(TAG, "Got:" + message.getBody());
                    // messages.add(fromName + ":");
                    // messages.add(message.getBody());

                }
            }
        }, filter);
    }
}
```

The problem is it seems to stop listening after being idle for a while. If I send chat messages straight away they get output.

Is the service getting stopped somehow? Is that the right place to put the packerlistener?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at a similar question [How to run a continuous process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027014/how-to-run-a-continuous-process/5027941#5027941). Also read about [START_REDELIVER_INTENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT) and [START_FLAG_REDELIVERY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_FLAG_REDELIVERY), maybe it will help.

Comment: Hello Athor I am facing same problem.My Packet Listener also stop to listen the packet after a Certain time.yo got its solution ?

Comment: No sorry, I abandoned the project....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have created a service, and in the onStart I use a AsyncTask to connect to the chat server, and then sets up a packetlistener.

I do not recommend that. Create your own thread, not an `AsyncTask`. `AsyncTask` is designed for things that will end in milliseconds or seconds, not minutes or hours.

> Is the service getting stopped somehow?

Quite possibly. Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and see what it tells you about your code.

You should be using `startForeground()` in your service, particularly if you plan on keeping the service running when your chat client activity is not necessarily in the foreground.